# Easier way to do mysql UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Is there an easier way to this update?

```
UPDATE mailbox SET toNew = 1, toDelete = 0 WHERE msgID = 1 AND msgFrom = 1

UPDATE mailbox SET fromNew = 1, fromDelete = 0 WHERE msgID = 1 AND msgTo = 1
```

I tried using an `IF` but it didn't work...

```
UPDATE mailbox SET IF(msgTo = 1, toNew, fromNew) = 1, toDelete = 0 WHERE msgID = 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could do the trick, though I prefer your original queries as they are more readable IMO

```
UPDATE mailbox SET toNew = IF(msgTo=1,1,toNew), toDelete = IF(msgTo=1,0,toDelete), fromNew = IF(msgFrom=1,1,fromNew), fromDelete = IF(msgFrom=1,0,fromDelete) WHERE msgID=1
```

Comment: I agree they are more readable but would one query not be faster than two? I am not pre-optimising, but it just stumbled me that this kind of `IF` after `SET` did not work!

Comment: @novactown.com SQL is very trict that way

Comment: This worked a treat! Thanks. When I actually see it like this, it does seem more logical this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about what logic you want (based on what flags and what permutations you have), but you can try something like this

```
UPDATE mailbox 
SET 
    toNew = msgFrom, 
    fromNew = msgTo,
    toDelete = CASE WHEN msgFrom = 1 THEN 0 ELSE toDelete END,
    fromDelete = CASE WHEN msgTo = 1 THEN 0 ELSE fromDelete END
WHERE 
   msgID = 1;
```